# Slow query execution even though written efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

This is my query:

```
With cte as (
    Select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By  d.OldInstrumentID ) peta_rn,   
        d.DocumentID
    From Documents d
    Inner Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID 
    Where 1=1  
       And (d.JurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 Or DocumentStatusID = 9)
       And d.DocumentStatusID <> 3 And  d.DocumentStatusID <> 8 
       And  d.DocumentStatusID <> 7 
       AND ((CreatedByJurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 Or DocumentStatusID = 9 Or CreatedByAccountID IN (Select AccountID From AccountsJurisdictions Where JurisdictionID = 1)))  
      And d.DocumentStatusID = 9
) 
Select
    d.DocumentID,
    d.IsReEfiled,
    d.IGroupID,
    d.ITypeID,
    d.RecordingDateTime,
    d.CreatedByAccountID,
    d.JurisdictionID, 
    Case 
        When d.OldInstrumentID IS NULL 
        THEN d.LastStatusChangedDateTime 
        Else d.RecordingDateTime 
    End as LastStatusChangedDateTime,
    dbo.FnCanChangeDocumentStatus(d.DocumentStatusID,d.DocumentID) as CanChangeStatus,
    d.IDate, 
    d.InstrumentID, 
    d.DocumentStatusID,
    d.DocumentDate,
    Upper(dbo.GetFlatDocumentName(d.DocumentID)) as FlatDocumentName
From Documents d
Inner Join cte on cte.DocumentID = d.DocumentID 
Where 1=1 
  And peta_rn>=80000 
  AND peta_rn<=80050 
Order by peta_rn
```

There are hardly 100,000 records in DB and yet this query takes about 2 seconds to execute to fetch just 50 records. Totally unacceptable! I even have indexes on most of the columns where join is used.

A single join is made in CTE's base clause but that is required. I know joins are killers but I need that 1 join. If this remove this piece of code:

```
And (d.JurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 Or DocumentStatusID = 9)
And d.DocumentStatusID <> 3 
And d.DocumentStatusID <> 8 
And d.DocumentStatusID <> 7 
AND ((CreatedByJurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 Or DocumentStatusID = 9 Or CreatedByAccountID IN (Select AccountID From AccountsJurisdictions Where JurisdictionID = 1))) 
And d.DocumentStatusID = 9
```

it runs very fast. Shows 0 second in SSMS. Any way to speed up this query? I need those conditions are they are not even so big. Why would conditions slow down the query? I already have indexes on CreatedByAccountID and other columns. Really annoying!

**Edit:**

Thanks for the responses. Some more details:

Many of you suggested to remove redundant conditions. Sorry this piece of SQL is formed dynamically in code and I pasted that version in SSMS and here. Removing those conditions from where clause don't help:

```
Where 1=1
  And (d.JurisdictionID = 1 Or d.DocumentStatusID = 5 Or d.DocumentStatusID = 9)
  And d.DocumentStatusID <> 3 
  And  d.DocumentStatusID <> 8 
  And  d.DocumentStatusID <> 7 
  AND ((CreatedByJurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 Or DocumentStatusID = 9 Or CreatedByAccountID IN (Select AccountID From AccountsJurisdictions Where JurisdictionID = 1)))  
  And d.DocumentStatusID = 9
```

As a matter of fact as soon I put where clause it slows down. So, even this one is slow:

```
 Where 1=1 
   And (d.JurisdictionID = 1 Or d.DocumentStatusID = 5 Or d.DocumentStatusID = 9)
```

Some more details. The order by clause in Row_Number() is deciding factor. `OldInstrumentID` which is of type varchar(14) is slow and takes 2 seconds whereas if I do order by `d.DocumentID` which is of type int, it works fine in 0 seconds even though I keep all those redundant conditions.

This is my execution plan:

[image]

**Update:**

I created indexes like this on each column and it seems to run super fast. Woot Woot!!!

```
Create NonClustered Index   IX_DocumentDate on Documents
(
    DocumentDate     

)
Include(
    JurisdictionID,
    JudgementTypeID,
    IDate,
    EfileDate,
    UserID,
    RecordingDateTime,
    ApprovedBy,
    ACEfileBankAccountID,
    LastStatusChangedDateTime,
    ACEfileCreditCardID,
    EfiledByUserID,
    ITypeID,
    IGroupID,
    InstrumentID,
    OldInstrumentID,
    [CreatedByJurisdictionID],
    CreatedByAccountID,
    [DocumentStatusID]      


      ,[Remarks]
      ,[InternalNotes]
      ,[ParentDocumentID]
      ,[FilingNumber]
      ,[StampData]      
      ,[Receipt]
      ,[ReceiptNo]
      ,[IsReEfiled]      
      ,[ImportedFromInstrumentID]

)
```

Comment: Could you post an execution plan?

Comment: It looks to me that you have too many conditions in `where`, but all of them will fail if d.DocumentStatusID not equal 9. Sorry, it's hard to read such queries (you are using table aliases only in some places - somewhere it's  `d.DocumentStatusID` , on other places it's `DocumentStatusID`

Comment: When posting questions on an international forum, it is best to avoid highly regional words such as "lac" or "lakh".  The more conventional term is 100,000.

Comment: Joins are not 'killers'. Properly written joins against properly designed tables are very efficient. Poorly written code, now...

Comment: Your code charges off the right-hand side of the page unnecessarily, making it extremely hard to read.

Comment: Please format your code better when posting.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possible reasons that the conditions could slow down your query:

- I suspect that the query engine has no choice but to perform index or table scans to get the values of the DocumentStatusID from your Documents table. However, from my reading, much of this work is redundant, because the last line of your condition states that DocumentStatusID must always equal 9. If the SQL Server engine is processing this condition last, it may be that it is performing many more table scans to evaluate the other conditions than it needs to. It may be that your other conditions could be re-written on the basis that you will only ever have Documents with a DocumentStatusID of 9 returned.
- There is a subquery inside your CTE which will be being executed every time a value from your CTE is requested. If the AccountsJurisdictions table is large and AccountID is not indexed then there may be a performance implication here.

Just as another note, the "WHERE 1=1" statements should probably be removed, as they will force the SQL Server engine to retrieve and process all rows I think - you're potentially working against the inbuilt query optimisation using this syntax.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the engine didn't remove the WHERE 1=1 in the query rewrite phase.

Answer (score 1):

Your CTE can be simplified in a variety of ways.  In particularly, you are checking for `d.DocumentStatusID = 9`, so any other references to `documentStatusId` can be removed.

However, I think the performance problem is due to the `in` clause embedded in the complex `where` logic.  `In` often optimizes very well in SQL Server.  In this case, though, I'm guessing that you are getting a nested loop join.  Try doing an explicit join instead:

```
    Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By  d.OldInstrumentID ) peta_rn,   
            d.DocumentID
    From Documents d Inner Join
         Users u left outer join
         on d.UserID = u.UserID 
         (select distinct AccountId
          from AccountsJurisdictions
          Where JurisdictionID = 1
         ) aj1
         on u.CreatedByAccountID = aj1.AccountId and
               (d.JurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 Or DocumentStatusID = 9) AND
               d.DocumentStatusID <> 3 And d.DocumentStatusID <> 8 AND
               d.DocumentStatusID <> 7 AND
               (CreatedByJurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 
                 Or DocumentStatusID = 9 Or aj1.AccountId is not NULL
                ) AND
               d.DocumentStatusID = 9
```

You can also try creating an index on `AccountsJurisdictions(JurisdictionId, AccountId)` so the index gets used for this portion.

Comment: Your syntax of using *(select distinct AccountId
          from AccountsJurisdictions
          Where JurisdictionID = 1
         ) aj1* is incorrect (atleast in SQL server). The query isn't compiling.

Comment: Obviously, I left the "WHERE" in there by mistake.  I also removed the "1=1".

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I meant. After fixing your other errors (eg. You have written *Documents d Inner Join
         Users u left outer join on d.UserID = u.UserID * instead of Documents d Inner Join
         Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID *), Iget compile time error for this: * (select distinct AccountId
          from AccountsJurisdictions
          Where JurisdictionID = 1
         ) aj1*. It looks like this doesn't work in SQL server however, I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

If d.DocumentStatusID = 9 then a lot of redundant conditions

```
;With cte as (
               Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By  d.OldInstrumentID ) peta_rn, d.DocumentID
               From Documents d
               Join Users u 
                    on d.UserID = u.UserID 
               Where -- 1 = 1 AND
               d.DocumentStatusID = 9 
               AND (CreatedByJurisdictionID = 1  
                    Or CreatedByAccountID IN (Select AccountID From AccountsJurisdictions Where JurisdictionID = 1)
                   )
               -- below redundant as  d.DocumentStatusID = 9
               --(d.JurisdictionID = 1 Or DocumentStatusID = 5 Or DocumentStatusID = 9)
               --And d.DocumentStatusID <> 3 
               --And d.DocumentStatusID <> 8 
               --And  d.DocumentStatusID <> 7 
               --AND (
               --      Or DocumentStatusID = 5 
               --      Or DocumentStatusID = 9 
               --    )  
             ) 
Select  d.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime -- ...
From Documents d 
Join cte 
  on cte.DocumentID = d.DocumentID 
Where -- 1=1 AND
     peta_rn>=80000 AND peta_rn<=80050 
Order by peta_rn
```

And is this even necessary?
Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID
If u is a FK then this will always be true

Comment: One that query is not "written efficiently" and two if you could not change the query then should have included that in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

I would try making the `DocumentstatusID`, `JurisdictionID` and `CreatedByJurisdictionID` as columns in CTE and the put the very complicated join clause as a WHERE on the final join.

I'm not surprised it's getting slow with all those 'not equals' cases and the complicated logic, as a 'not equals' is not a fast operation in itself. I'd be trying to simplify all the code around those.

Comment: Is the where is moved then the ROW_NUMBER would not be the same.

Comment: @Scott Earle: How will you get proper numbering of row_number if you put where joins at final?